# Allowed memory size is being exhausted and I need help figuring out why

Tags: php

I currently use godaddy for hosting my website and I recently checked my error_log and I keep getting this error:

PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 19648 bytes) in /home/jringeisen/public_html/bookling.co/includes/thumb.class.php on line 16

this is the default resource limit that godaddy has set:

Resource Limits memory_limit    Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (32MB)    64M

From what I understand this is more then enough, I need help pin pointing where the error is. I ran error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); on all my image upload files and received no errors. I don't want to increase the memory size, from what I understand that doesn't fix the problem. I know there are multiple questions on this exact error but I have yet to be able to find an answer that helped fix the problem.

```
<?
class Thumb{
function Thumb(){}
/**********************************************
* $name: orginal file name
* $filename: thumb file name
* $new_w: new proposed width
* $new_h: new proposed height
**************************************************/
function createthumb($name,$filename,$new_w,$new_h)
   {
/*     echo $name ;
   echo "<br>";
   echo $filename ; 
   die();
*/      if (preg_match("/\\.jpg$/",strtolower($name))){$src_img=imagecreatefromjpeg($name);}
        if (preg_match("/\\.jpeg$/",strtolower($name))){$src_img=imagecreatefromjpeg($name);}
        if (preg_match("/\\.png$/",strtolower($name))){$src_img=imagecreatefrompng($name);}
        if (preg_match("/\\.gif$/",strtolower($name))){$src_img=imagecreatefromgif($name);}

        $old_x=imageSX($src_img);
        $old_y=imageSY($src_img);

                    if ($old_x > $old_y) 
                    {
                        $rat = $old_y/$old_x*100;
                        $thumb_w=min($new_w,$old_x);
                        $thumb_h = floor($thumb_w * $rat / 100);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $rat = $old_x/$old_y*100;
                        $thumb_h=min($new_h,$old_y);
                        $thumb_w = floor($thumb_h * $rat / 100);

                    }


        $dst_img=ImageCreateTrueColor($thumb_w,$thumb_h);


        imagecopyresampled($dst_img,$src_img,0,0,0,0,$thumb_w,$thumb_h,$old_x,$old_y); 
        if (preg_match("/\\.png$/",strtolower($name)))
        {
            imagepng($dst_img,$filename); 
        } else if (preg_match("/\\.jpg$/",strtolower($name)) || preg_match("/\\.jpeg$/",strtolower($name)) ) {
            imagejpeg($dst_img,$filename); 
        }else if (preg_match("/\\.gif$/",strtolower($name))) {
            imagegif($dst_img,$filename); 
        }
        imagedestroy($dst_img); 
        imagedestroy($src_img); 
       }//end function
  }        
?>
```

Comment: GDlib often requires more memory than you might think it would

Comment: Quick note: Constructors should be called `__construct`. Calling them the same as the class is a compatibility feature.

Comment: @scrowler I haven't set a limitation on image size, and the script won't allow anything over 2mb, if I try and upload an image over 2mb it gives me this error. I should have enough memory to be able to upload a 2mb photo correct?

Comment: @jonathon no. GD is interpreting the image that you're uploading, and it needs a hell of a lot more memory than the filesize to do that

Comment: It is trivial to make a billion-pixel image that takes up only a few kilobytes on disk.

Comment: alright I increased the memory and now I am getting a parse error: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS) in /home/jringeisen/public_html/bookling.co/includes/thumb.class.php on line 3 and I can't find it. I add the memory portion of the code so line 3 is actually class Thumb{.